# How exactly do Adapters for ArrayLists in Android Studio work?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I'm trying to build a to-do list app in Android Studio that saves the list as a text file and then when you open the app again if there's a text file with stored tasks it will initialize the arraylist in the app with that data.

It was all working well with the arraylist and its adapter until I had to update the arraylist with the stored file. Now it prints but instead of printing the string with the task it prints a weird internal thing like "com.example.todolist.MyData@fe7bcc9"

I've looked around and can't quite find if I can use the same adapter twice (update it?) and generally any info on your experiences using this would be really helpful.

main java code:

```
package com.example.todolist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;


import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class MainJava extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

     // 1. Some variables and definitions
        ListView listView;
        ArrayList<MyData> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        MyAdapter adapter, adapter2;
        private EditText taskEntered;
        private int itemPos;
        private final String file = "list.txt";
        private String line;
        private OutputStreamWriter out;


     // 2. Method: The classic ON CREATE
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            // locate the widgets: edit text (to get string) and list view (to put string)
            taskEntered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterTask);
            listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

            // attach listener to list view
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            taskEntered.setText("");

            //hide title and icon in action bar  EDIT TO HIDE SAVE AND CLOSE
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

            //open output stream
            //try {
               // out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(file,MODE_PRIVATE)); // also try MODE_APPEND
          //  } catch (IOException e) {}

            readFromFile();

        }

     // 3. Method: ON CREATE OPTIONS MENU
     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
         return true;
     }


     // 4. Method: ON OPTIONS SELECTED
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

         int itemID = item.getItemId();  // get id of menu item picked

         switch (itemID) {

             case R.id.add :
                 addNewTask();   // prints entered task in list view
                 return true;

             case R.id.delete :
                 deleteTask();
                 return true;

             case R.id.update :
                 updateTask();
                 return true;

             case R.id.save :
                 saveToFile();
                 return true;

             case R.id.close :
                 saveToFile();
                 finish();

             default: super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }
         return false;
     }


    // 5. Method: PRINT NEW TASK in list view and ADD NEW TASK to arrayList
     public void addNewTask() {
         // get string from the edit text
         String taskString = taskEntered.getText().toString();

         // create ArrayList values
         arrayList.add(new MyData(arrayList.size() +1, taskString));
         // TESTING: arrayList.add(new MyData(2, " Robert"));

         //create custom adapter and connect to ListView
         adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

         taskEntered.setText("");                          // clear edit text bar after adding item

     }

     // 5. Method:
     public void addNewTask(String string) {

         // create ArrayList values
         arrayList.add(new MyData(arrayList.size() +1, string));

         //create custom adapter and connect to ListView
         adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     // 6. Method: Listener, when you click on an item in list view it does this:

     // listener is passed into the position of the item that was clicked?

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            itemPos = position;
            // you click on an item in list view
         String task = arrayList.get(position).getName();      // get name of task
         int numTask = arrayList.get(position).getNum();        // get number of task

         // set edit text field to show the item you just clicked
         taskEntered.setText(numTask + " " + task);
     }

     // 7. Method: Delete a task

     public void deleteTask() {

         // remove the arrayList item in the position that was clicked
         arrayList.remove(itemPos);

         // loop through items and reassign numbers
         for (int i=0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
             arrayList.get(i).setNum(i+1);
         }

         //create custom adapter and connect to ListView
         adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

         taskEntered.setText("");                                     // clearing edit text widget
     }

     // 7. Method: Update a task

     public void updateTask() {

         // get string from the edit text
         String taskString = taskEntered.getText().toString();

         String updatedString= taskString.substring(2);  // so that the task number is not repeated

         arrayList.get(itemPos).setName(updatedString);

         //create custom adapter and connect to ListView
         adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

         taskEntered.setText("");                                     // clearing edit text widget
     }

     // 8. Method: Save contents of app to a file

     public void saveToFile() {
         try {
             // writing!

             //open output stream try catch
             try {
                 out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(file,MODE_PRIVATE)); // also try MODE_APPEND
             } catch (IOException e) {}

             // loop through items in ArrayList
             for (int i=0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
                 line = arrayList.get(i).toString();        // grab each line from the to do list
                 out.write(line + " \n");             // write each line on TEXT file
             }
             out.close();                           // close output stream

         } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e("IOTest", e.getMessage());
         }
     }

     // 9. Method: Read from file

     public void readFromFile() {

         // check if file already exists, if not - finish, if yes - open stream and update app with that

            // A) if file doesn't exist leave method
            if ( !fileExists(this, "list.txt") ){
                return;
            }

            // B) if file already exists, open a stream, read it, copy it to ToDoList app
            else {
                arrayList.clear();
                try {

                    // reading!
                    InputStream in = openFileInput(file);            // open stream for reading from file
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String str = null;

                    // loop to read lines from file and print in app
                    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {      // str = each line in the text file OR MAYBE THIS STRING IS THE RAW CODE FROM EACH LINE

                        addNewTask(str);
                        //str.toString();
                        //arrayList.add(new MyData(arrayList.size() +1, str));    // create ArrayList value of the string in the text file
                       // adapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);            // create custom adapter and connect to ListView
                        //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                    reader.close();               //close input stream

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("IOTest", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
     }

     // 10. Method: Check if file exists

     public boolean fileExists(Context context, String filename) {
         File file = context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
         if(file == null || !file.exists()) {
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }


    }
```

Adapter.java code:

```
package com.example.todolist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

/*
 ADAPTER
  inflate xml file called row.xml
  get references (id's) for widgets in row.xml
  add each value on arrayList to its widget
 */

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<MyData> arrayList;
    private TextView listNum, name, contactNum;

    // calling 3 arg constructor of parent class and storing values stored in
    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyData> arrayList) {
        super(context, 0, arrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    // all the action is in this getView method
    // calls layout inflater class and gives it the layout of the row
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // call inflater to create a View from an xml layout file
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        // get references for row widgets
        listNum = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listNum);   // id´s of widgets in MyAdapter.java
        name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.task);

        // ArrayList provides values that go along in a row when getView is finished it goes through entire ArrayList and
        listNum.setText(" " + arrayList.get(position).getNum());
        name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

my data code:

```
package com.example.todolist;

public class MyData {

    private int listNum;
    private String name;

    //constructors
    public MyData(int num, String name) {
        this.listNum = num;
        this.name = name;
    }

    //accessors and mutators
    public int getNum() {
        return listNum;
    }
    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.listNum = num;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Comment: Which line of code you print and got `com.example.todolist.MyData@fe7bcc9`

Comment: Ran the entire app in android studio! So I'm guessing all of main.java ran first

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at how to produce a [mre] for your problem. Also you need to be able to tell us where your problem came from, saying "the entire app" makes it impossible for us to help!

Answer (score 0):

please add this method in your MyData class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return listNum+","+ name;
}
```

here is full class just copy and paste then this will work

```
public class MyData {
    private int listNum;
    private String name;
    //constructors
    public MyData(int num, String name) {
        this.listNum = num;
        this.name = name;
    }
    //accessors and mutators
    public int getNum() {
        return listNum;
    }
    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.listNum = num;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return listNum+","+ name;
    }
}
```